# Mongodb - How to transform nested object in an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I import a data file from an external source into my database. This data has nested objects in an array in a nested object. Example:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59de680a8a042e19b4ac4895"), 
"_embedded" : {
    "identification" : [
        {
            "name" : "Bill Brasky", 
            "id" : "brasky9z5", 
            "type" : "Client"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Merle Haggard", 
            "id" : "mh2017", 
            "type" : "Vendor"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Captain American", 
            "id" : "1a1a1a1", 
            "type" : "Client"
        }
    ]
}}
```

I want to use the aggregate operation to see only the 'id' and 'type' values. I know how to use aggregate to return the results if there is no array or nested document.

```
db.users.aggregate(
{ $project : {
    _id : 0 ,
    id : 1 ,
    type : 1     
}})
```

I think I need to use $unwind but my brain is winding instead. How can I update my aggregate operation to project my required fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$map` to transform the embedded array.

Something like

```
db.users.aggregate({
  "$addFields": {
    "_embedded.identification": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$_embedded.identification",
        "as": "result",
        "in": {
          "id": "$$result.id",
          "type": "$$result.type"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: That's great, thanks @Veeram. Is there an easy way to get the output in individual records rather than just as added fields. This will be needed as I will be using $out to export to new documents in another table. (That part I have figured out)

Comment: You are welcome. Add `{$unwind:"$_embedded.identification"}` before `$out` stage